# Xamarin forms list view items source not updating

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having a problem with my xamarin forms list view. I have created a list view that has an items source that is binded to a List of a custom class. In the app.xaml.cs, I have the exact same list. In another form, I am updating the list that resides in app.xaml.cs. When the first form with the list view is brought back up, on appearing I set the local list that is binded to the list in app.xaml.cs. But, the items in the list view UI dont update. Can someone please help me with this?

MainPage.xaml (with list view):

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TrackExpensesApp.MainPage">

        <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
            <ToolbarItem Text="+"
                        Clicked="OnAddExpenseClicked" />
        </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

        

    <ListView x:Name="ExpenseEntriesListView"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ExpenseEntries}"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        ItemSelected="ExpenseEntriesItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="10"
                                RowDefinitions="Auto, *"
                                ColumnDefinitions="Auto, *">
                    <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    Text="{Binding Name}"
                                    VerticalOptions="End" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1"
                                    Text="{Binding DateCreated}"
                                    VerticalOptions="End" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Text="{Binding Category}"
                                    VerticalOptions="End" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

`
MainPage.xaml.cs (with list view):

`

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public IList<ExpenseEntry> ExpenseEntries { get; set; }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        async void OnAddExpenseClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ExpensesEntryPage());
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            ExpenseEntries = (Application.Current as TrackExpensesApp.App).ExpenseEntries;
            
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        async void ExpenseEntriesItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ExpenseEntry selectedItem = e.SelectedItem as ExpenseEntry;

            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ExpensePage());
        }
    }
```

`

App.xaml.cs:

`

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public IList<ExpenseEntry> ExpenseEntries { get; set; }
        public IList<string> Categories { get; set; }

        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Load in all expenses before loading in the main page
            ExpenseEntries = new List<ExpenseEntry>();

            Categories = new List<string>();
            Categories.Add("Monthly");
            Categories.Add("Vacation");
            Categories.Add("Other");

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

            BindingContext = this;
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }
    }
```

`
I would truly appreciate it if someone would get back to me as soon as possible. Thank you!

Comment: where is the code where you update the list?

Comment: Hi Jason! I update the code in another form. Here is the code to that. '(Application.Current as TrackExpensesApp.App).ExpenseEntries.Add(new ExpenseEntry
            {
                Name = NameEntry.Text,
                Category = CategoryPicker.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                Details = DetailsEditor.Text,
                StartDate = StartDatePicker.Date,
                EndDate = EndDatePicker.Date
            });'

Comment: Use an ObservableCollection instead of a List

Comment: Hello! I have done this but now I am getting an exception that says invalid cast. Can yiou please help?

Comment: Please update your question to include your revised code, and note the **exact** line that is causing the exception

Answer (score 1):

We need to call [OnPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobject.onpropertychanged?view=xamarin-forms) in `setter` method  to notify that a change happened on a property ,so that the UI would change after then.

#### MainPage

Change your code as below

```
private IList<string> expenseEntries;
public IList<string> ExpenseEntries { 
  get
  {
      return expenseEntries;
  }
  set 
  {
      expenseEntries = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();  //add this line
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hello! I updated my code to match this but it didn't help. I changed this in both app.xaml.cs and mainpage.xaml.cs. I wonder why it isn't working?

Comment: Use  `ObservableCollection` instead of  `List`

Comment: Hello! I have done what you have said but now I am getting an exception that says invalid cast.

Comment: Change the `IList` to  `ObservableCollection` both  in `Page` and `App` .

Comment: Hello! I have done that but I still get the exception

Comment: Could you provide a basic, reproducible project here ? It works fine on my side .

Comment: Hello! Here are some images of my code: App.Xaml.cs: https://pasteboard.co/KhKgccX.png Main Page Code Behind: https://pasteboard.co/KhKgHcu.png Main page UI: https://pasteboard.co/KhKgVpH.png Expense Entry Class: https://pasteboard.co/KhKh5C4.png Expense Entry Page Code: https://pasteboard.co/KhKhhk5.png Expense Entry Page UI: https://pasteboard.co/KhKhsIO.png

Comment: Hello! Have you figured out what is causing the problem?

Comment: Sorry for late reply , your code works without any problem on my side .IF possible could you proivde a basic, reproducible project here  ? You can upload it on github and attach the link here .